# How to exclude an item from "wrap_content" in an Android View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a drop down menu in a header. When a button is pressed the drop down menu comes down. The problem is all the other views in the activity are positioned with `android:layout_below="@id/header"` and drop down menu pushes everything down because it increases the header's height. I need to exclude the drop down menu from `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in order to prevent that. Is it possible?

NOTE: I can solve the problem programmatically, I just want to learn whether it is possible to exclude an item from "warp_content" in XML.

Comment: what you want to say..clarify it.

Comment: Added more text, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Ok, revised it. Let me know if it is still not clear and I will try again :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot exclude ViewGroup's child from being considered during layout calculations unless you set `android:visibility=gone`. But you may want to replace your main container with `RelativeLayout` which then would let you position some elements as you wish

Comment: Yeah, I use android:visibility=gone initially but when I need to show the drop down menu I change the value programmatically to "visible" and that messes up with the height. I already use RelativeLayout. Thank you for your answer. At least now I know it is not possible to exclude an item from "wrap_content".

Answer (score 1):

Start off with a `RelativeLayout`, than add all you items in the `RelativeLayout`, and lastly, put your header file at the bottom of your xml (at the bottom in the sense, that it will show over all other elements). E.g. something like this:

```
<!-- Root element -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- First text view, the margin_top defines space for your header -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" android:layout_margin_top="height_of_your_header"/>

    <!-- TextView below another view -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2" android:layout_below="@+id/tv1" />

    <!-- Your Header file, which will be positioned over all elements
    - When closed, it will fit above @id/tv1
    - When opened, it will float above the other elements -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/header" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The height of the header changes from screen to screen depending on the png file, I cannot really use a constant value for the android:layout_margin_top. I think I will end up setting up the height programmatically. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case, you should do it programatically for the easiest way out

Comment: Yeah, I ended up setting up the height programmatically. Thank you for your help!